# how to get bold text in the kendo UI in panel bar text?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

```
@(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
.Name("panelbar")
.ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Single)
.Items(PanelBar =>
{
    PanelBar.Add().Text("abcd")
           .Expanded(true)
           .Content("abcd-have to show in bold text ");

}))
```

The "abcd" text has to display the as in bold !???how to get it, but text not in .content box!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the LinkHtmlAttributes() method with whatever style/class you want:

```
@(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
    .Name("panelbar")
    .ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Single)
    .Items(PanelBar =>
    {
         PanelBar.Add().Text("abcd")
            .LinkHtmlAttributes(new { style = "font-weight: bold;" })
            .Expanded(true)
            .Content("abcd-have to show in bold text ");
}))
```